# Unpacking SequenceMatcher loop results

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

What is the best way to unpack `SequenceMatcher` loop results in Python so that values can be easily accessed and processed?

```
from difflib import *

orig = "1234567890"

commented = "123435456353453578901343154"

diff = SequenceMatcher(None, orig, commented)

match_id = []
for block in diff.get_matching_blocks():
    match_id.append(block)

print(match_id)
```

String integers represent Chinese Characters.

The current iteration code stores match results in a list like this:

```
match_id
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=4), Match(a=4, b=7, size=2), Match(a=6, b=16, size=4), Match(a=10, b=27, size=0)]
```

I'd eventually like to mark out the comments with `"{{"` and `"}}"` like so:

```
"1234{{354}}56{{3534535}}7890{{1343154}}"
```

Which means, I am interested in unpacking the above `SequenceMatcher` results and do some calculations on specific `b` and `size` values to yield this sequence:

```
rslt = [[0+4,7],[7+2,16],[16+4,27]]
```

which is a repetition of `[b[i]+size[i],b[i+1]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Unpacking `SequenceMatcher` results to yield a sequence

You can unzip `match_id` and then use a list comprehension with your expression.

```py
a, b, size = zip(*match_id)
# a    = (0, 4,  6, 10)
# b    = (0, 7, 16, 27)
# size = (4, 2,  4,  0)

rslt = [[b[i] + size[i], b[i+1]] for i in range(len(match_id)-1)]
# rslt = [[4, 7], [9, 16], [20, 27]]
```

Reference for `zip`, a Python built-in function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

## 2. Marking out the comments with `"{{"` and `"}}"`

You can loop through `rslt` and then nicely append the match-so-far and mark out the comments.

```py
rslt_str = ""
prev_end = 0

for start, end in rslt:
    rslt_str += commented[prev_end:start]
    if start != end:
        rslt_str += "{{%s}}" % commented[start:end]
    prev_end = end
# rslt_str = "1234{{354}}56{{3534535}}7890{{1343154}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
from difflib import *

orig = "1234567890"
commented = "123435456353453578901343154"

diff = SequenceMatcher(None, orig, commented)

match_id = []
rslt_str = ""
for block in diff.get_matching_blocks():
    match_id.append(block)

temp = 0
for i, m in enumerate(match_id[:-1]):
    rslt_str += commented[temp:m.b + m.size] + "{{"
    rslt_str += commented[m.b + m.size: match_id[i+1].b] + "}}"
    temp = match_id[i+1].b
```

so that `rslt_str == "1234{{354}}56{{3534535}}7890{{1343154}}"`

Comment: I like your code for being concise, but guess it is much harder for a beginner to understand and follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from difflib import *

orig = "1234567890"
commented = "123435456353453578901343154"
diff = SequenceMatcher(None, orig, commented)

a, b, size = zip(*diff.get_matching_blocks())

start = {x + y : '{{' for x, y in zip(b[:-1],size)}
end = dict.fromkeys(b[1:], '}}')
rslt = {**start, **end}

final_str = ''.join(rslt.get(ix,'') + n for ix, n in enumerate(commented)) + '}}'

print(final_str)
```

Output:

```
'1234{{354}}56{{3534535}}7890{{1343154}}'
```

**Explanation**:

As `SequenceMatcher().matching_blocks()` is iterable, so you can directly unpack it to your variables.

1. Then create a dictionary with starting indices as keys and `{{` as value.
2. Similarly, create a dictionary with ending indices as keys and `}}` as value.
3. Unpack both the dictionaries in `rslt`.

Then form a list by passing the characters of `commented` as default value to [`dict.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/5431791) and for indices in the `rslt` dict, prepend character with corresponding curly braces. Finally join into string.